# How can I change some text when a checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form with three items with checkboxes and prices. In a paragraph underneath I have an area for the total price, and an area for the items selected. How can I update these two areas when each checkbox is checked?

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="milk" id="checkbox" value="10.00"/>£10.00<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="eggs" id="checkbox2" value="20.00"/>£20.00<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="checkbox3" value="30.00"/>£30.00<br/>
If you buy <span>name of items here</span>, it will cost you a total of £<span>price here</span>.
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

How can I achieve this with jQuery or JavaScript? I don't really want to use a textbox for putting the values in, I'd rather they were in-line text. So I want the object names in the first bit, and the total price in the second.

Comment: You'll want recalculate the cost on the server too, in case someone forges a POST with a lower value. Minus values once caused an application to pay out money with orders.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. This price is simply a label though, the actual product with its price is calculated server-side. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var names = $('form :checked').map(function(){
        sum += (this.value - 0);
        return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
    
    var spans = $('form span');
    spans[0].innerHTML = names;
    spans[1].innerHTML = sum;
});
```

html

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="milk" id="checkbox" value="10.00"/>£10.00<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="eggs" id="checkbox2" value="20.00"/>£20.00<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="checkbox3" value="30.00"/>£30.00<br/>
    If you buy <span>name of items here</span>, it will cost you a total of £<span>price here</span>.
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

demo

## [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/WS5Pu/)

Answer (score 2):

I have used jquery for acheiving your requirement.

Try this -

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="milk" id="checkbox" value="10.00"/>£10.00<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="eggs" id="checkbox2" value="20.00"/>£20.00<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="checkbox3" value="30.00"/>£30.00<br/>
If you buy <span id="name">name of items here</span>, it will cost you a total of £<span id="price">price here</span>.
<input type="submit"/>
</form>


$(document).ready(function(){

 $('input[type="chechbox"]').click(function()[

  if($(this).is(':checked')){

   $('#price').html($(this).val());
   $('#name').html($(this).attr('name'));

  }else{

   $('#price').html('Price');
    $('#name').html('name');
  }

 });

});
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough. I don't want to choose just once item. I want to be able to sum up the total prices. And add and remove the three items as I wish.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JS (untested)

```
   handleCheckbox = function(){
      if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementByTagName("span")[0].innerText = this.attributes["name"].value;
        document.getElementByTagName("span")[1].innerText = this.value;
      }
    }
```

However, there should be radio instead of checkbox. Add `onClick="handleCheckbox"` on checkbox

Comment: Nah I want to use check boxes as I want to be able to select multiple items, and list their total combined price, as well as all their names in a list form.